# Play Framework 2.3.7 - logger levels don't seem to be respected in production/staging mode

Tags: logging, playframework, logback

So we're running into a strange symptom with our logging configuration with Play 2.3.7. We have an `application-logger.xml` defined and is being loaded properly (file inlined below).

When we run the app in dev mode with `activator run` all settings in there are respected - logger levels, log file, rotation, log patterns, etc. However when we run the app in staging mode with `activator stage` or prod mode with `activator dist` our logger levels for `application` and `play` either seem to be ignored or overridden. They are both set to `WARN` but `application` logs at `DEBUG` level.

All other settings in the file are respected - we verified this by changing some of the others to make sure they took.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this? We even examined the archives generated by `activator stage` etc and nothing seems out of whack there, but we can't seem to get rid of the `application` `DEBUG` mode. Also, `ERROR` messages don't seem to be written to the log file but to `stdout`.

Thank you! Our prod `application-logger.xml` is below:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/application.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- Daily rollover with compression -->
            <fileNamePattern>logs/application-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <queueSize>1024</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="com.cwbase.logback.RedisAppender">
        <source>play-core</source>
        <host>[HIDDEN]</host>
        <port>6379</port>
        <tags>prod</tags>
        <key>logstash</key>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LOGSTASH-ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
        <queueSize>1024</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SENTRY" class="com.getsentry.raven.logback.SentryAppender">
        <dsn>[HIDDEN]/dsn>
        <tags>env:production</tags>
    </appender>

    <appender name="SENTRY-ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="SENTRY"/>
        <queueSize>1024</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ACCESS_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${user.dir}/web/logs/access.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>access-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} %message%n</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="access" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="be.objectify.deadbolt.java.actions.AbstractDeadboltAction" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="application" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="play" level="WARN"/>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH-ASYNC"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ASYNC"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SENTRY-ASYNC"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Just to add to the above, also tried renaming the file and using `-Dlogger.resource=<filename>` -- no dice.